# Process single element array when converting XML to JSON (<?xml-multiple?>)

Tags: java, json, xml

I'm using org.json.XML.toJSONObject() method to convert an XML string to JSON. Here is a sample XML string that I need to convert.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jsonObject>
   <data>
      <?xml-multiple accounts?>
      <accounts>
         <Id>123</Id>
         <creationDate>2021-10-21T15:43:00.12345Z</creationDate>
         <displayName>account_x</displayName>
      </accounts>
   </data>
   <links>
      <self>self</self>
      <first>first</first>
      <prev>prev</prev>
      <next>next</next>
      <last>last</last>
   </links>
   <meta>
      <totalRecords>10</totalRecords>
      <totalPages>10</totalPages>
   </meta>
</jsonObject>
```

Here, 'accounts' is an element of an array and contains only a single element. But the org.json library cannot detect this. It can detect only if there are multiple elements.

My question is, is there a library that I can use to detect a single element array using the available  tag in the XML string?

Comment: You need to explain what makes this question different from the many others that ask about XML arrays to JSON. Maybe it is the <?xml-multiple accounts?> ... but you have not said so.

Comment: You may add attribute array=true and use underscore-java library, static method U.xmlToJson(xml).